# In a room there are eight lights. Each light can be switched on and off independently of the others. In how many ways can the room be lit with-?

Tags: combinatorics

In a room there are eight lights. Each light can be switched on and off independently of the others. In how many ways can the room be lit with-

five lights on?

at least five lights on?

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of ways to **choose** $5$ lights from $8$ lights?

Comment: i have figured out '5 lights on' as 56,but i can't get at least five lights on..

Comment: yes,its 8*7*6*5*4 divided by 5*4*3*2 which is 56.

Comment: I know binomial coefficients but i cant get the at least five lights on part..

Comment: at least 5 lights means:either (5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8).  Replace "OR" by "+"

Answer (score 2):

**With respect to the Multiplication Principle**

If one desires to light a room with exactly 5 lights - obviously 5 lights must be on out of the possible 8 lights. If one decides to use the multiplication principle, they must adjust the answer to account for the fact that the **order** in which these lights are on  does not matter! Therefore our answer is

$$\mathrm{Exactly\ 5\ Lights}=\frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4.}{5 \times 4 \times 3\times 2\times 1} = \frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4.}{5!}$$

Answering the outcome of at least 5 lights is equivalent to finding the number of outcomes for exactly 5, 6, 7 and 8 lights independently and summing the individual answers.

$$\mathrm{At\ Least\ 5\ Lights}=\frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4}{5!} + \frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3}{6!} + \frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2}{7!} + \frac{8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1}{8!} $$

Of course, these calculations can look nicer using binomial coefficients. If you have not learn't this then this answer is for you.

Answer (score 1):

To turn exactly 5 lights on we will have to choose any 5 of the 8 available lights, this can be done in $8\choose5$$=56$ ways.

In order to turn at least 5 lights on, we will have to subtract the cases of turning 0,1,2,3,4 lights on from the total number of cases. i.e.

$2^8$-$8\choose4 $-$8\choose3 $-$8\choose2 $-$8\choose1 $-$8\choose0 $$=93$

Comment: Why not just do $8\choose 5$+$8\choose 6$+$8\choose 7$+$8\choose 8$?

Comment: @JanDvorak you are right! but, subtracting non required from total looks more intuitive.

Comment: @JanDvorak the answer will be same i.e. 93 in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to have five lights on is the number of way to **choose** (see André Nicolas's comment) a $5$-element subset of a set of $8$ elements. This is what is called a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

$$\binom{8}{5}$$

For at least five, you can add up all of the possibilities for the number of lights on:

$$\binom{8}{5}+\binom{8}{6}+\binom{8}{7}+\binom{8}{8}$$