# How many ways can a row of lights be turned on and off

Tags: combinatorics

Say you have a row of 4 lights. Each light-bulb can be turned on/off independently.  How many lighting combinations could you come up with?

[image]

**My research:**

Before asking this question I searched the forum to make sure this wasn't a duplicate. I found similar questions, but they had restrictions which I'm not imposing.

For example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084232/in-a-room-there-are-eight-lights-each-light-can-be-switched-on-and-off-independ) required that a number of lights always be left on, and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555845/a-light-can-only-be-turned-on-if-there-is-a-light-next-to-it-turned-on-in-how-m) imposed a lighting pattern.

I simply want to know without restrictions how many combinations there could be.

Reading the answers to the linked questions above I learned about [Pascals triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

[image]

Studying the triangle it appeared to me that the number of combinations possible for N (the number of lights in a row) is the sum of all the numbers in the row of pascal's triangle that has the same amount of numbers as n+1.

For example if I had 1 light, there are 2 combinations, on or off.

Pascals second row (the number of lights + 1) the sum of that row adds up to 2. Thus representing the total number of combinations.

Is that correct, and if it is, is there a more formal algorithm to represent this sort of problem without having to draw out a pascal triangle for large data-sets?

Comment: Every light bulb can be turned on or off independently of the other ones. This gives you $\{\text{on}, \text{off}\} \times \dots \times \{ \text{on}, \text{off} \} = 2^{d}$ choices where $d$ is any number of lightbulbs.

Comment: @VHarisop wow yes that is a simple way to think about it. Thank you! I see how Pascals triangle basically does the same thing in a more complex way.

Comment: Since you introduced the Pascal triangle, it's worth mentionning that the sum of the $n$th row of this triangle is $2^n$ (the first row is the $0$th). See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519832/proving-by-induction-that-sum-k-0nn-choose-k-2n

Comment: Each element of a row in Pascal's triangle is added into two elements in the row below, which is one way to see that the sum doubles each time.

Comment: Plenty of answers but here's another: think of it as a binary number.

Comment: @badjohn that was actually why I asked the question! It was for a programing problem on a binary array. I don't know why I didn't think to just convert it to decimal and the outcome would be the same.

Comment: @YAHsaves As a programmer, you should recognise a binary number.  Think of each bulb as a bit and then the block of four is a nybble (one hex digit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about saying that, since you have two possibilities for each light bulb, then you have $16(=2\times2\times2\times2)$ possibilities?

Comment: That seems easy enough! Thank you, very clear concise answer. I see how pascals triangle is basically doing the same thing but in a more complex way.

Answer (score 5):

Each light has two positions and is independent of the others.  By the multiplication principle there are $2^4=16$ possibilities.  The row of Pascal's triangle that goes $1-4-6-4-1$ shows that there is one possibility with no lights on, four with one light on and so on.  The sum is duly $16$

Answer (score 1):

The 'nth' row of Pascal's triangle has the coefficients for $(x+ y)^n$.  Taking x= y= 1 the sum of those coefficients is $(1+ 1)^n= 2^n$.